# How to access state of another reducer in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

So I am new to React and I am trying to build a simple shopping app. I am also using Redux store and Saga.
I have two reducers.

A `productsReducer` which has the following initial state:

```
const initState = {
  products: [],
  loading: false
}
```

I am loading products data in the `products` array with a `get` API call.

I have another reducer called `cartReducer` which has the following initial state and has to implement and 'add to cart' action:

```
const initState = {
  loading: false,
  cartItems: [],
  cartCount: 0
}
```

Code for adding to cart is:

```
case 'ADD_TO_CART':
  let addedItem = state.products.find(product => product.id === action.id)
  // products array contained list of products
  let existed_item = state.cartItems.find(product => action.id === product.id)
  if (existed_item) {
    existed_item.quantity += 1
    return {
      ...state,
      cartItems: state.cartItems,
      cartCount: state.cartItems.length,
    }
  } else {
    let newItem = Object.assign({}, addedItem);
    newItem.quantity = 1;
    return {
      ...state,
      cartItems: [...state.cartItems, newItem],
      cartCount: state.cartItems.length,
    }
  }
```

I am combining both reducers as follows:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  cartReducer,
  productsReducer
})
export default rootReducer;
```

Initially I had actions of both reducers in one place so I could access the `products` array in my `ADD_TO_CART` function. But now that I have split the actions into separate reducers I don’t know how to access the `products` array from the `productsReducer` inside `cartsReducer`.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reducers` should not depend on each other in `redux`. You can imagine a [reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#splitting-reducers) as a function that receives an action and an existing state, and produces a new state from that. That way, every call with the same parameters always will return the same results.

When you are modelling your state in your app, you should aim to not have duplication of entities. In your case, you are adding a product to the cart, but that product is already stored in the list of products. Having the product on both places would create duplication (what happens if that product is modified in some way? You would have to change it twice).

Instead, you can store the product id in the cart, and use a [selector](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data) to combine both pieces of the state whenever you need to access it.

So your state could look like:

```
{
 products: [ { id: 1, details: {} } ],
 cart: { items: [1,2,3] }
}
```

and you could do a function similar to:

```
function productsInCart(state) {
  const ids = state.cart.items
  const products = findWithId(state.products, ids)
}
```

you will notice that it might get cumbersome to work with the state. That's why [normalizing the state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) might make it easier to work with.

Comment: I was adding the entire product to the cart because I wasn't storing the cart in a DB. It only existed in the store. I now have a table for the cart. I access the products in the Component itself and send the product Id's only to the back end(DB).